# Problems with notice

Tags: 7

I'm new in Drupal. I had to migrate a page from a client to another server. The page work well on a development test but not anymore.

I have these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: highlighted en include() (línea 126 de /home/portal/public_html/modules/system/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_first en include() (línea 138 de /home/portal/public_html/modules/system/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_second en include() (línea 144 de /home/portal/public_html/modules/system/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: hotel en drupal_theme_initialize() (línea 100 de /home/portal/public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object en _drupal_theme_initialize() (línea 146 de /home/portal/public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object en _theme_load_registry() (línea 335 de /home/portal/public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: hotel en theme_get_setting() (línea 1431 de /home/portal/public_html/includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object en theme_get_setting() (línea 1478 de /home/portal/public_html/includes/theme.inc).
```

The link to the page is: http://www.portaldelcuadrado.com.ar/
What can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the `theme` on the test site and the live site the same `theme` with the same `regions` defined. The drupal theme() function is complaining that `regions` are not defined which the body (node) content is trying to be placed in.